# How to freeze an Rc data structure and send it across threads

Tags: multithreading, rust, reference-counting

My application works in two phases:

1. A large data structure is created, involving lots of temporary objects and using reference counting for heap management
2. The data structure is made read only, anything that is still alive is parked, and the resulting structure is sent to another thread to be read.

(For extra concreteness, the application is a language server, and the data structures are processed individual files, which are processed single threaded but the results of which have to be passed across threads.)

Currently, I am using `Arc<T>` to manage the data structure, but because phase 1 is large and expensive and single threaded, I would like to switch it to use `Rc<T>`. But `Rc` is neither `Send` nor `Sync` for good reason, and I can't send the data structure or a reference to it unless basically everything in the program uses thread-safe primitives.

I would like to reason that after phase 2 starts, we don't need reference counting anymore; thread 1 (the owner) is not allowed to touch the reference counts and thread 2 (the borrower) is not allowed to clone the data, only look at it, so it can't touch the reference counts either. I know that `Rc` will not provide this set of guarantees, because you could clone an `Rc` given the shared reference. Is there a safe API for this pattern? Ideally I would not have to copy any data when going from phase 1 to phase 2.

Here's a toy implementation, just to put some code to it. The function `phase1()` generates lots of garbage before returning a data structure of type `T`, which is then analyzed in a read only way in `phase2()` on another thread. If you change `Arc` in this code for `Rc`, you will get an error because it can't be sent across threads.

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;
use crossbeam::thread::scope; // uses the crossbeam crate for scoped threads

enum T { Nil, More(Arc<T>) }

fn phase1() -> T {
    let mut r = T::Nil;
    for i in 0..=5000 {
        r = T::Nil;
        for _ in 0..i { r = T::More(Arc::new(r)) }
    }
    r
}

fn phase2(mut t: &T) {
    let mut n = 0;
    while let T::More(a) = t {
        n += 1;
        t = a;
    }
    println!("length = {}", n); // should return length = 5000
}

fn main() {
    let r = phase1();
    scope(|s| { s.spawn(|_| phase2(&r)); }).unwrap();
}
```

Comment: Why does it need to be sent to another thread? From what I can tell after reading this, `phase1` uses a single thread then it passes to `phase2` where it again uses a single thread. It sounds to me like it could just stay entirely in a single thread without any issues.

Comment: The example is oversimplified. In reality thread 1 has other things to do, and there are multiple thread 2's reading thread 1's data and combining it with their own work, in their own version of phase 1. The point of the example isn't so much to justify the architecture as to sketch the data flow in the form of valid code.

Comment: What type of data structure is your `enum T`? There may be an existing library for your use case. Currently it looks like some form of linked list or tree so I'm wondering if maybe the reference counters could be replaced with boxes.

Comment: `phase1` is actually the interpreter for a garbage collected scripting language. There is quite a lot of sharing in the real thing, so the reference counting is important. (There are even a small number of cycles, and right now I'm just dealing with the memory leak, because I don't know a good off the shelf arena based `Gc` type.)

Comment: I know you are looking for a safe solution but if there is none; since it is only going to be read after phase1 then you can use unsafe to force `Rc` to implement `Sync` , according to your logic this should work fine: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b88aba51fcc639d5a13274c1576e09fa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not exactly clear to me what you are trying to accomplish in the larger picture. My takeaway is that you don't want to use an `Arc` just so that the data structure can be sent between threads, which only occurs once. One can do this by wrapping the type in another type for which you manually implement `Send`. This is really, really unsafe because the compiler will not be able to guard against race conditions.

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::thread::spawn;

// Foo is not Send because it contains a Rc
struct Foo {
    bar: Rc<bool>,
}

// Foowrapper is forced to be Send
struct FooWrapper {
    foo: Foo,
}
unsafe impl Send for FooWrapper {}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, ");

    // We can't send a Foo...
    let foo = Foo {
        bar: Rc::new(false),
    };

    // This blows everything up, and there is no
    // protection by the compiler
    // let secret_bar = Rc::clone(&foo.bar);

    // ...but we can send a FooWrapper.
    // I hereby promise that I *know* Foo is in a
    // state which is safe to be sent! I really checked
    // and no future updates in the code will harm me, ever!
    let wrap = FooWrapper { foo };
    spawn(move || {
        // Unwrap the Foo.
        let foo: Foo = wrap.foo;
        println!("{:?}", foo.bar);
    })
    .join()
    .unwrap();
}
```

In the above example, we send a data structure that contains an `Rc`, which is not `Send`. By wrapping in a `FooWrapper`, it becomes `Send`. However, it is left to us to be **100% sure** that at the moment where `FooWrapper` is sent to the other thread, the inner `Foo` is safe to be sent. For instance, this is not true if the main thread has a clone of one of `bar` (e.g. `let secret_bar = Rc::clone(&foo.bar);`) and holds it beyond the point of sending. This would allow both threads to drop their version of `bar` unsynchronized, wrecking the `Rc`.

Comment: Okay, I figured that something like this would be necessary. Note that I'm not actually moving the `Foo` to the other thread, only borrowing it (I can't move it in the real application because there are multiple readers). The lasting unsafety here makes me sad, though. As long as we don't clone any of the Rc's on thread 2, we don't have to worry about data races, right? The only real danger is if thread 1 drops the data structure while thread 2 is still looking at it, but it seems like it would be possible to make that work with the lifetime system.